# REDUX : Is it possible my data not deleted after refreshing the page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a project in React and i am using Redux. I get a data from API and I add these data to an array. However, when I refresh the page, my data gone and my array becomes empty. Is it possible to make it permanent? How can I do that? I couldt find any example about that.

```
import ActionTypes from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const myCities = [];
const initialState = {
  aCity: {},
};

export const WeatherReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.GETBY_CITYNAME:
      myCities.push(payload);
      return { ...state, aCity: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [redux-presist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) library or you can use locaStorage.